# how to pass JavaScript value to PHP page

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

It is showing undefined function in PHP page.And i made every possible way it is not working for me.Please guys help me with this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="myDiv">Welcome to stackoverflow</div>
    </body>
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
            var mb = $('#myDiv').text();
            $.ajax({
                action : "six-cuf.php",
                type: 'POST',
                data: { 'mb': mb},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    alert(mb);   
                }
            });
        });
    
    </script>
</html>
```

PHP CODE

```
<?php  
  $fname = $_POST['mb'];
?>
```

Comment: Remove the quotes here `{ 'mb': mb}` and wrap your jQuery with a document ready function.

Comment: You are receiving a PHP `undefined function` error? Please provide the relevant PHP code if that is the case, and the error message.

Comment: Jay Blanchard: it's not working after removing quotes and document ready function

Comment: user3783243: This is the PHP code where i want to get those values in PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var mb = $('#myDiv').text();
  $.ajax({
    action : "six-cuf.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: { mb: mb},
    success:function(data)
    {
      alert(mb);   
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I tested same code (Just copy & paste) in localhost and its working. I did not get any error.

Comment: If you got the value in console means your data you is going through ajax call. Can you share your entire PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this JQuery Post Method

**Javascript Code**

```
$.post("six-cuf.php", {'mb': mb}, function (data) {
      console.log(data);
 });
```

**PHP code**

```
<?php
$fname = $_POST['mb'];
echo $fname;
?>
```

Comment: I got the value in console.But i didn't get in PHP page.It still showing undefined function

Comment: can you share your PHP code? I think there must be a function in your PHP page which was not defined.